# Stop queueing of subsequent JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I'd like to stop a second (or nth) showConfirmDialog from being displayed, if the user didn't yet dismiss the first one, but I can't find a way of doing that.

Comment: So you're saying that multiple confirmation dialogs are showing at once? Can you give us a (short, concise) code example to show how you're calling them?

Answer (score 1):

The [`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) is blocking. Check the return value from the call to determine if you should show the next dialog, something like this:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "First question?");

if (result != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {

    int nextResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Next question?");
    ...
}
```

---

If you have a list of questions to ask you can use a loop and break when the user dismisses a dialog:

```
for (String question : questions) {

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, question);

    if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
        break;

    // handle (yes/no) the response
    ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I didnt explain myself well. I have a runnable inner class which is listening for a certain text string on a socket. If that arrives, then JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog pops up. That's all fine. Except if the remote peer sending that string cancels at the other end, and then decides to send the string again anew, the receiving client gets another ConfirmDialog displayed, and its that second or subsequent ones that I want not to allow.

Comment: I still think @dacwe's answer fits ok for your problem. Anyway, maybe you should make socket comm. more robust by adding some kind of ack messages, or even sending a message to show the fisrt one have been canceled.

Comment: I've already got code like that - it doesnt work. There can't be a return ACK, becausethe receiving client just leaves the dialog hanging on his screen - I want to make sure another one doesnt get put up as well - I dont care if the receiving client never clicks YEs or No, I just dont want another dialog constructed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question (and comments) correctly you have a certain `Thread` which listen for texts on a socket, and when it receives text it shows a new dialog with the new text.

I solved a similar problem by showing a dialog which contained a `JTextArea`. When my `Thread` received new text, I appended the text to the `JTextArea`, and showed the `JTextArea` when it was not already shown.

When the user dismissed the dialog, I cleared the `JTextArea`.

Small side-note: you better update your question with the extra information you added in the comments as those comments make it more clear what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using straight JDialog then (JOptionPane is just a shortcut for creating a JDialog). You can use a WindowListener / windowClosing event to determine if you should show the next JOptionPane

Comment: Sorry again guys - my mistake - had a wrong boolean value in the if clause that was meant to be blocking subsequent message dialogs. Got it sorted, and thanks this time.